# Changing style using JS & HTML works, JS & CSS doesn't always

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using JS & HTML markup
**Always works:** [Codepen](http://codepen.io/dhust/pen/GgXKNL/?editors=001)

```
if (document.forms['myForm'].name.value == '') {
    name.style.background = "pink";
}
else {
    name.style.background = "white";
}
```

Using JS & CSS
**Doesn't always work:** [Codepen](http://codepen.io/dhust/pen/azaozy/?editors=001)

```
if (document.forms['myForm'].name.value == '') {
    // give this element the .error class from the css file
    name.className = name.className + " error";
}
else {
    // this removes the error class
    name.className = name.className.replace(" error", ""); 
}
```

Why is JS & CSS inconsistent? I would like to use this approach since I can just apply an error class to each of the elements I want to effect.

Comment: If you want something that will update as the client uses it you can expand on this http://codepen.io/NewToJs/pen/MYqgOm?editors=001 this will add an event listener to anything with the class of required and listen for the input event. The function required() will need much more work but I thought I would show you this anyway. *You can expand on this to display errors for each input before the user submits*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you hit your submit button and a field isn't filled out, `error` is added to the `classList` property; if you submit more than once, multiple classes will be added. Whereas when removing the class, `.replace(' error', '')` will only replace the first instance of `error` it comes across.

You can use regex to find *all* instances of `error`:

```
name.className = name.className.replace(/ error/g, "");
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxJOwP)

Sidenote: You can take advantage of [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) but its browser support is limited.

Comment: I didn't even think that I kept adding the .error class. Beautifully done.